# CMake FetchContent propagate content variables

Tags: cmake

I have to repositories in my code. I'd like to connect the second, supporting, repository using `FetchContent`:

```
FetchContent_Declare(
    repo2
    GIT_REPOSITORY "git@bitbucket.org:data/repo2.git"
    GIT_TAG        master
    GIT_PROGRESS   true
)
```

The `repo2` has a main CMake file that performs `find_package` to locate and load some external package:

```
find_package(something
    "6.0.1"
    REQUIRED
    COMPONENTS
        core
)
```

The load process will populate many useful internal variables that specify architecture and tools and such. However, those variables are not propagated to the top level `repo1` with `FetchContent`.

What is the best way to have the same variables in `repo1` CMake files as in `repo2` after `find_package` is done?

Comment: "What is the best way to have the same variables in `repo1` CMake files as in `repo2` after find_package is done?" - Just repeat `find_package` in a scope where you need it.

Comment: Yes, that's one way. But I was hoping to keep everything encapsulated inside `repo2` files.

Comment: "I was hoping to keep everything encapsulated inside `repo2` files" - Not sure what do you mean by "incapsulated", but results of `find_package` are implied to be **internal** for the `repo2` project. Only normal (non-IMPORTED) targets are provided as an "interface" of the project. As a developer of the `repo1` project you may say: "Hey, I want to use a package `something` **too**, for my own purposes. But I want the package found to be the same as in `repo2`". For that use `find_package` again. It won't recalculate CACHE'd variables. And calculation of non-CACHED ones gives the same result.

Comment: Thanks @Tsyvarev for the explanation